# Swift 3 Breaks My Objective C and Swift Handler/Closure Compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift3

**SIAlertView** is an external Objective C library I use in my project

**In Swift 2.2** this line below compiles fine

```
class func showAlert(title title : String, message: String, confirmHandler: (SIAlertView!) -> Void) {

    ...
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle(OK_TITLE, type: SIAlertViewButtonType.Default, handler: confirmHandler);
    alertView.show();
}
```

**But now in Swift 3 there is an error message saying**

[image]

```
Cannot convert value of type 'class func showAlert(title title : String, message: String, confirmHandler: (SIAlertView!) -> Void)' to expected argument type 'SIAlertViewHandler!'
```

**From the Objective C Class I find that**

**SIAlertView.h**

```
@class SIAlertView;
typedef void(^SIAlertViewHandler)(SIAlertView *alertView);
```

**SIAlertView.m**

```
- (void)addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title type:(SIAlertViewButtonType)type handler:(SIAlertViewHandler)handler
{
    SIAlertItem *item = [[SIAlertItem alloc] init];
    item.title = title;
    item.type = type;
    item.action = handler;
    [self.items addObject:item];
}
```

Could anyone explain this please? Because it previously works fine in Swift 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change This**

```
class func showAlert(title title : String, message: String, confirmHandler: (SIAlertView!) -> Void)
```

**To This**

```
class func showAlert(title title : String, message: String, confirmHandler: (SIAlertView?) -> Void)
```

In Objective C, this parameters could be nil, therefore we must declare it as optional.